# Why can't I print a chart from a windows service using NetworkService account?

Tags: c#, windows-services, printing, permissions

I have a C# windows service which is running under the **NetworkService** account. It occasionally needs to print a [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(VS.100).aspx) object which I do by simply calling:

```
chart.Printing.Print(false); // suppress the Printer Dialog
```

The weird thing is it seems works fine running as a console application.

The only way it will work is if I run the service under a local admin account.

Answer (score 3):

You probably needed access granted for [System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printingpermission.aspx). Reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(VS.80).aspx), you find the following:

> Classes within the
>   System.Drawing.Printing namespace are
>   not supported for use within a Windows
>   service or ASP.NET application or
>   service. Attempting to use these
>   classes from within one of these
>   application types may produce
>   unexpected problems, such as
>   diminished service performance and
>   run-time exceptions.

Comment: Yeah the weird thing is it doesn't throw an exception it just ignores the call, which would come under *unexpected problems*. How would I grant access to the PrintingPermission class? Do I just give NetworkService access to the specific folder the assembly is in?

Comment: @James- have you also considered creating a low privilidge service account to run the code under?

Comment: @Richard just tried it out there, created a new user with the basic User template permissions. Didn't work. There must be a permission somewhere in an admin account that the NetworkService/Basic is missing. Again no exception under minimal account.